# How do I insert data into Vue using Express, without putting the API call code in Vue?

Tags: security, express, oauth, vuejs2

In Vue, I understand that any Javascript included in the Vue files will be exposed to the browser (The User-agent in OAuth model). I want to make an API call to an API protected using OAuth 2 and have the data returned from the API call then displayed in the Vue app. Using OAuth, I need to use an Access token only known to the client server (node/express server) and I do not want to reveal the access token to the browser (user-agent).

I tried to see if I could do it using vue-axios, but that forces me to add the auth-token to the logic within vue, which means the browser can access the access token, which seems really unsecure.

So, I thought that I could make the API call on the node/express server that hosts the Vue application. Then, have the data included in the Vue app and send it to the user's browser with the data. The Vue app would then be rendered as normal. That would keep Auth Token hidden from the user's browser. However, I got stuck trying to include JSON data extracted from the api using Express in the Vue app.

How can I insert data into Vue using express, without putting code from the API call into vue?

Note: I'm new to Vue, so if anyone thinks that there is better way to do this securely, I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you're trying to over-think this. You're not going to out-think the designers of OAuth. Consumers of apis need access tokens. Your OAuth access token is secure, in the sense that it can't be modified to get extra rights, and it should be short-lived, requiring regular re-authentication. You security lies in the fact that even if your user recovers the token, it won't let him do anything you're not happy for him to do anyway.

Comment: So what's the point of auth code grants? I thought that the point was never to allow the user agent to see the token. If it's fine to let user agents see the token, what is the point? What kind of application would make use of auth codes?

Comment: I don't know your situation in detail, and I've limited experience with OAuth. Web apps cannot securely store secrets, so you should be looking at the PKCE flow?